# How do I know when a project file has become modified in Visual Studio using the Automation and Extensibility API?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

[`TextEditorEvents.LineChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.texteditoreventsclass.linechanged.aspx) seems like a good event to listen to to check the to see if a code file has become modified. What event can I listen to to see when the project or solution file has become modified (compiler options changed, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Projects are covered by the Project interface.  Which has a [Saved property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.project.saved.aspx) to indicate that the project has changed since it was last saved.  The ProjectEvents interface can provide events.

Comment: [ProjectEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectseventsclass.aspx) has no event for when project becomes modified. That's what my question is about.

Comment: Of course it does.  When items are added or removed you definitely want to take a look at the Saved property.

Comment: Read my question. I'm looking for an event that fires when I change, for example, the output path. Or that's a good proxy, like an event that fires when I open project's or solution's property pages.

Comment: Read MSDN, find that mythical event you think exists.